# add image below x axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am trying to add an image below the x axis label in a matplotlib plot, but as I move the image position further down, it will eventually go outside the plot area. Here is a minimum example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.offsetbox import (OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox)

im = plt.imread('plane.jpg')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.set_xlabel("my label")

imagebox = OffsetImage(im, zoom = 0.05)

ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction', box_alignment=(1.1, 1), frameon = False)
ax.add_artist(ab)

fig.savefig("example.png")
plt.show()
```

Where the image can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOpK6.jpg) and the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhOrP.png).

I could not find online any example that does that. I would like the plot area to be automatically extended below the x axis in order to accommodate the image. Is it possible in matplotlib?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Does `plt.tight_layout()` (just before `plt.show()`) work in your case?

Comment: No, unfortunately not...

Comment: @RigelF.doC. what version of Matplotlib are you using?  `plt.tight_layout()` works for me, as does setting `layout='constrained'` in the call to `subplots`.  I have Matplotlib v3.8

Comment: Actually, since you said "I would like the plot area to be automatically extended below the x axis in order to accommodate the image", you probably want to use `fig.savefig("example.png", bbox_inches="tight")`, which alters the size of the figure.  The suggestions in the previous comments change the size of the objects within the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment above into an answer: setting `bbox_inches="tight"` in the call to `savefig` will change the size of the saved figure to fit the artists it contains.  I have tested this with Matplotlib versions between v3.6 and v3.8.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.offsetbox import (OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox)

im = plt.imread('plane.jpg')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.set_xlabel("my label")

imagebox = OffsetImage(im, zoom = 0.05)

ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction', box_alignment=(1.1, 1), frameon = False)
ax.add_artist(ab)

fig.savefig("example.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much RuthC! You are right: `bbox_inches="tight"` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use figsize and set position to increase size of plot to show, but I dont know which IDE you use, tbh I run your code in colab, and shows full picture, try this way, it might help

```
# Create a figure with a larger height to accommodate the image below the x-axis label
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 8))

# Create the axes
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.set_xlabel("my label")

# Set the position of the axes to leave space for the image
ax.set_position([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.6])
```

Comment: Thanks Murad. I am running the code from the command line. In my case, `figsize` applies to the entire plot (including the graph), so after a while it won't make any difference to keep increasing the height: the image will go below the plot area... That's because the graph area grows vertically as well, while I wanted it to remain there (with its default size) and to have only more space below the x axis.

Comment: I have just figured out that Spyder will also show the full picture in the plots pane, but the figure saved by `fig.savefig` is still wrong. Since I am producing many figures to be inserted into a beamer presentation, I need the saved version...

Comment: The only way I managed to make it work was by playing with the parameters of `ax.set_position` and `box_alignment` until you manage to fit everything, but it is a very specific solution and the image will go out-of-place as soon as you change any of those parameters. It would be good to have the plot area be extended automatically to accommodate for figures placed around it.

Comment: Jupyter notebooks (as used in Google Colab) use the inline backend, which automatically uses `bbox_inches="tight"`.  I am guessing Spyder also uses the inline backend since you see the same behaviour there.